# How to search Gmail mails that have only one conversation

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

Is there any way I can find all the emails that I sent but have not been replied to by anyone? (One email conversation.)

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30523/sent-item-filters-in-gmail/30532#30532

Comment: Related: [Manage un-replied Gmail conversations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/8671/354)

Answer (score 2):

It looks impossible with the standard search bar.

I tried searching for conversations that do not contain "Re:" or "Fwd:", but there is something broken about GMail search when it comes to that!

- If I use search string `subject:"fwd:"`, I get conversations with
  forwards.
- If I use search string `-subject:"fwd:"`, I get *all e-mail* (not
  just conversations without forwards!)
- If I use search string `subject:"re:"`, I get conversations with replies.
- If I use search string `-subject:"re:"`, I get *all e-mail* (not just
  conversations without replies!)

So obviously searching for `-subject:"fwd:" -subject:"re:"`, which really *should work*, fails.

`-(subject:"re:" OR subject:"fwd:")` does not work either.

`-{subject:"re:" OR subject:"fwd:"}` does not work either.

So obviously combining that search with from:your e-mail address would not work either.

---

A kludge would be:

1. Make a new label (e.g.`NRF`, for "No Replies or Forwards", or "gmail's search is NeRFed").
2. Make a new filter that applies the new label to to all e-mails from yourself (make it retroactive).
3. Search for `subject:"fwd:"`, and remove the new label from all of the results.
4. Search for `subject:"re:"`, and remove the new label from all of the results.
5. (Do the same for `subject:"fw:"` since some e-mail applications use that.)
6. Search for the new label (e.g. `label:NRF`).

That should give you what you want.